# QML: How to remove invalid property name (M16)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a basic QML library with a CPP class, a qrc file and a qml file:

CPP file:

```
qmlRegisterType( QUrl( "qrc:/MyType.qml" ), "LibA", 1, 0, "MyType" );
```

QRC file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>MyType.qml</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: 'blue'
    width: 50
    height: 50
}
```

When i use it in main.qml works fine but keep saying invalid property name "color" (M16) and its the same for "width" and "height". I know this can stay this way until works, but can be fixed?

Here my main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

import LibA 1.0

Window {
    visible : true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Hello World"

    MyType {
        height: 100
        width: 100
        color: 'yellow'
    }
}
```

Im using Qt 5.14.2, Thanks in advance, sorry my bad english.

Comment: Is your main.qml not in the resource file? Why don't you import `QtQuick 2.12` in the component as you do in other files?

Comment: The main.qml file its in a diferent qrc because its a application. The MyType.qml its in a library i put the same verson o qtquick and keep saying the same thing.

Comment: I edit the post, QtQuick to 2.0 in an attempt to get an answer to help me correct the problem thx btw

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem with the following code (main.qml):

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

No error when building on Desktop Qt 5.15, but M16 errors for the properties width, height, visible and title when building for Android Qt 5.15

Then I used

> ApplicationWindow

instead of

> Window

This code works for Android:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```